# How to pass an array into a class?

Tags: perl

I am confused about how to pass an array into a package:

The main code

```
use Person;
my @array=(1,2,3);
$object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem",\@array);
```

package

```
package Person;
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { 
        _firstName => $_[0],
        _lastName  => $_[1],
        _array  => $_[2],
    };      
    # Print all the values just for clarification.
    print "First Name is $self->{_firstName}\n";
    print "Last Name is $self->{_lastName}\n";
    print "Array is $self->{_array}\n";

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Print the result of the array is empty. How do I fix the code to get the values of the array?

```
First Name is Mohammad
Last Name is Saleem
Array is
```

Comment: The code you show cannot print what you show it does. It would print `Array is ARRAY(0x...)`, because the attribute is arrayref and you need to dereference it -- `print "Array is @{$self->{_array}}\n";`

Comment: Don't use `new Person(...)` but rather `Person->new(...)`.  Always have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

`$self->{_array}` is reference to array => derefference it.

```
my @array = qw(a b c);
$self->{_array} = \@array;    

print "Array is @{$self->{_array}}\n";
print " foreach: $_\n" foreach @{$self->{_array}};
for( my $i=0; $i<=$#{$self->{_array}}; $i++) {
  print " for: $i:  $self->{_array}[$i]\n";
}
```

Comment: `for( my $i=0; $i<=$#{$self->{_array}}; $i++)` is far more readable if it's written `for my $i (0 .. $#{self->{_array}})`

Comment: @DaveCross IMHO It is more readable for **perl** programmer.  IMHO **perl** would not ask this question.

Comment: Simpler code is more readable for anyone :-) The C-style `for` loop gives for more opportunities to introduce fence-post errors.

Comment: True perl programer would write `for my $i ($[ .. $#{self->{_array}})` ;-)

Comment: Not in this case - where you need the index for the output